# Should I remove subdomains?

Tags: seo, google, subdomain

I am going to optimize a site which has two subdomains since a long time ago. They are pointing to the site's main domain and are well-indexed by Google. I've read in a SEO book however that having several urls pointing to the same content is a bad practice bcauses waisting 'link juice'.

Now I am wondering whether removing the subdomains is a good idea SEO-wise? regarding that it causes many references from Google lead potential visitors to nowhere. It is specially helpful to know  how long does it take for Google to flush references to the subdomains. I appreciate your hints about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would ask myself at this point is: are those subdomains helpful or are they only 301's. If they have some content on them, if they are part of your website I would keep them there.

On the other hand, if they are just 301's I don't think Google likes them too much. I mean, you can get two links from the outside which in many cases add more link juice than the internal ones, so I would dump your 301's and go with more outside links.

Regards,

Daniel.

Comment: Google wouldn't care if they are 301s. What Google tends to frown on is serving up the same content on both subdomain.example.com and example.com. Or, for that matter, on two unrelated domains.

Comment: Yes and no, Kris. If you think of it just Search Engine-wise, I don't think Google is that smart to see that a 301 is just there for the sake of a 301, but on the other hand if you would like to have a solid project on the long run don't just look at a link from a 301 and make your site good. Is the subdomain useful for something? Yes, keep it. No, lose it. It's just like tags, they get in the search engine but they will also get you in trouble if you have too many.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say to keep 301 redirect to your main domain. Google will still index it and you'll have no problems with users getting wrong/blank pages